# Regex to match text in URL only as the last part?

Tags: .net, regex, iis-7

I am trying to construct a regular expression that will match the following URL:

`www.mydomain.com/testPhrase`

but NOT match

`www.mydomain.com/directory/stuff/morestuff/testPhrase/index.aspx?blah=foo`

for an IIS URL Rewrite Rule.

I started with `^.*testPhrase` but that matches both. What is the regex syntax to say only match if there is nothing after testPhrase but there can be anything before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use ^.*testPhrase$ - that would ensure that testPhrase is always at the very end.

Comment: I knew it would be easy...I just couldn't search for it based on the terms I was using. I just thought of...what about an optional trailing slash? I guess testPhrase or testPhrase/ should work.

Comment: Best way to handle that is ^.*testPhrase/?$ :)